# Continuously updating an array and grabbing its value in search filter bar React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I will literally rip out my hair from my head because of how long I've been working on this. I cannot figure out why my filterArray (which is updating properly in my console and filtering itself based on the search from the searchUser function) is working but when I output it onto my screen in my App it keeps saying it's empty? I want it to continuously update the way my searchUser function does but I'm not sure how to do this. Should I call searchUser in my big return statement at the end? Otherwise my filterArray shows up as empty (which is what I'm actually trying to output), and response just copies the full name of PDF names and doesn't update on the screen or narrow down my list based on my search (which is what filterArray does). I think this is because my useEffect function runs once and grabs the filterArray when its empty and just keeps it empty and doesn't reinitialize it.

Sorry if this is confusing but I am just losing it. I also dont want the MyComponent function to return the array items as a  component, but as a  but if I change it my code tells me I cant return things that are text as a list. Please please help.

```
const searchUser = async (input) => {
  var filterArray = [];
  //nametoURL is a dictionary that stores a full list of pdf names from Firebase
  Object.keys(nameToURL).map((item) => {
    if (item.includes(input) && !filterArray.includes(item)) {
      filterArray.push(item);
      console.log("FOUND A MATCH");
      console.log("MATCH IS: ", filterArray);
    } else {
      console.log("NO MATCH");
    }
  });

  return { filterArray };
};

const Map = ({ navigation }) => {
  var [filterArray, setFilterArray] = useState([]);
  var [userInput, setInput] = useState([]);
  var [] = useState([]);
  var [result, setResult] = useState({});

  function MyComponent({ response }) {
    console.log(response);
    return <Text>{Object.values(response)}</Text>;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // You can await here
      const response = await searchUser(userInput);
      setResult(response);
      setFilterArray(filterArray);
      // ...
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search For A Map (Case Sensitive)..."
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              searchUser(text), setInput(text);
            }}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
      <ScrollView>
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}> Camp Map </Text>
        <MyComponent response={result} />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're no setting the `result` state with the result from the `searchUser` call when the text changes. You can declare a function callback and do that there to have a cleaner code.

```
function MyComponent({ response }) {
  console.log(response);
  return <Text>{Object.values(response)}</Text>;
}

const Map = ({ navigation }) => {
  var [filterArray, setFilterArray] = useState([]);
  var [userInput, setInput] = useState([]);
  var [] = useState([]);
  var [result, setResult] = useState({});

  const onChangeText = async (text) => {
    setInput(text);
    const response = await searchUser(text);
    setResult(response);
    // not sure when or were you are assigning filterArray though
    setFilterArray(filterArray);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      // You can await here
      const response = await searchUser(userInput);
      setResult(response);
      setFilterArray(filterArray);
      // ...
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search For A Map (Case Sensitive)..."
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
      <ScrollView>
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}> Camp Map </Text>
        <MyComponent response={result} />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Making API calls every time the user types is not recommended, you can check out this pattern to debounce the call for usability https://gist.github.com/simonw/c29de00c20fde731243cbac8568a3d7f

Comment: response is still not updating, even though filterArray is from my searchUser function. This is because in my useEffect, it is only updating response once and not matching it to filterArray from searchUser. How do I grab the continuously updating array?

Comment: So I was updating and setting my filterArray in my searchUser function shown in my code above. For some reason though the updated value wouldn't get passed onto my Map() function. With your solution, text wasn't being initialized anywhere as well so onChangeText doesn't know what text is. Also, isn't an API call making my code fetch info from an online resource and parse through it? I make the API call at the beginning once don't I? Again I am a beginner so I am not sure about these things.

Comment: @UchihaAlchemist sorry, `text` is the value the handler receives, updated

Comment: @UchihaAlchemist I thought you were omitting the code for the call to firebase in your `searchUser` function. If you already load all the data you need somewhere else, it is unnecessary for it to be async or to debounce the call.

Comment: AHHH thank you so so so so much. I am getting a new error now but that has to do with me grabbing local variables that grab stuff from Firebase, so I might need help later on just with how to grab return values from functions but that will be posted as another question. When I made it global it worked with your function, so I know that the code you provided for me worked, so I just need to figure out how to grab it locally. You have helped me so much. Thank you.